# When app comes back to foreground it shows splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone

When my comes back to the foreground, it shows splash screen for a while, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGeKu.gif).

This only happens on iPhone 6 and later.

If you have ever had this experience, sharing the solution would be appreciated!

Comment: can you post your code? so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes its a bug.. I also Face that.

Comment: @Madhu thx, but I can't post this code , you know it not belongs to me . I post a picture about this bug.

Comment: What is on your splash screen? Is that the black screen with "Background" on it that is shown in the GIF?

Comment: @fishinear no no no ,not  splash screen ,that  "Background" screen is my desktop wallpaper .

Comment: So, your problem is that the desktop wallpaper shows through for a second?

Comment: @fishinear  yep , the desktop wallpaper shows and come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found the reason.

-----reason-----

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(NSIntegerMin, NSIntegerMin) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

-----change-----

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

That the splash-screen shows up for a moment before your app's UI comes up is **normal**. That is the whole purpose of the splash screen, to fill the small moment before your UI is ready.

What is **not** normal is the black screen with the red "background" text on it that comes up for a moment. That is **not** your desktop wallpaper, because that does not have the text on it. So that is likely something that you do in your app yourself.

I suggest that you concentrate your debugging efforts on where the black screen comes from:

- set breakpoints in applicationWillEnterForeground: and
  applicationDidBecomeActive: to see at what time the black screen
  comes up
- check your xib for any (hidden) black screen
- enable slow-motion animations in XCode to better see what is happening